# Vault TLS on Docker - cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

Tags: docker, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to run TLS on Valut using docker. At first generate certificates and run docker container with Vault server mode. After that I run `vault init` command that returns error:

> Error initializing: Put https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/init: x509: cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

I could use -tls-skip-verify but is not a solution.

I generate certs using openssl.cnf file:

```
[ ca ]
default_ca = testca

[ testca ]
dir = .
certificate = $dir/cacert.pem
database = $dir/index.txt
new_certs_dir = $dir/certs
private_key = $dir/private/cakey.pem
serial = $dir/serial

default_crl_days = 7
default_days = 365
default_md = sha256

policy = testca_policy
x509_extensions = certificate_extensions

[ testca_policy ]
commonName = supplied
stateOrProvinceName = optional
countryName = optional
emailAddress = optional
organizationName = optional
organizationalUnitName = optional
domainComponent = optional

[ certificate_extensions ]
basicConstraints = CA:false

[ req ]
default_bits = 2048
default_keyfile = ./private/cakey.pem
default_md = sha256
prompt = yes
distinguished_name = root_ca_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = root_ca_extensions

[ root_ca_distinguished_name ]
commonName = hostname

[ root_ca_extensions ]
basicConstraints = CA:true
keyUsage = keyCertSign, cRLSign
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ client_ca_extensions ]
basicConstraints = CA:false
keyUsage = digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1, 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ server_ca_extensions ]
basicConstraints = CA:false
keyUsage = digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1, 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.0 = localhost
DNS.1 = 127.0.0.1
DNS.2 = 0.0.0.0
```

These commands are used to generate CA cert.pem and key.pem:

```
openssl req -x509 -config openssl.cnf -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -out cacert.pem -outform PEM -subj /CN=MyTestCA/ -nodes

openssl x509 -in cacert.pem -out cacert.cer -outform DER
```

To run docker container I use:

```
docker run --cap-add=IPC_LOCK -e 'VAULT_LOCAL_CONFIG={"listener":[{"tcp":{"address":"127.0.0.1:8200", "tls_cert_file":"/vault/ca/cacert.pem", "tls_key_file":"/vault/ca/private/cakey.pem"}}], "backend": {"file": {"path": "/vault/file"}}, "default_lease_ttl": "168h", "max_lease_ttl": "720h"}' -p8201:8200 --name vault-server -v/tmp/vault-conf/ca-keys:/vault/ca vault server
```

Docker mounts folder with certificates which are used in Vault conf file.

There are docker logs:

```
This usually means that the mlock syscall is not available.
Vault uses mlock to prevent memory from being swapped to
disk. This requires root privileges as well as a machine
that supports mlock. Please enable mlock on your system or
disable Vault from using it. To disable Vault from using it,
set the `disable_mlock` configuration option in your configuration
file.
==> Vault server configuration:

                     Cgo: disabled
              Listener 1: tcp (addr: "127.0.0.1:8200", cluster address: "127.0.0.1:8201", tls: "enabled")
               Log Level: info
                   Mlock: supported: true, enabled: true
                 Storage: file
                 Version: Vault v0.9.6
             Version Sha: 7e1fbde40afee241f81ef08700e7987d86fc7242

==> Vault server started! Log data will stream in below:
```

Now after exec command `vault init` inside docker container it returns above error.

Generated cacert.pem file does contains 127.0.0.1 IP address in SAN.

```
X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Basic Constraints:
            CA:TRUE
        X509v3 Key Usage:
            Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
            DNS:localhost, DNS:127.0.0.1, DNS:0.0.0.0
```

Where I make a mistake?

Comment: (1) IP addresses in SAN should have type IP not type DNS. Type DNS is used for DNS names and type IP is used for IP addresses, which is why they have those names. (2) You're calling it a CA cert but using it as a server (listener) cert, which is very misleading. You're also giving it KeyUsage for a CA, which probably won't work for a server. (minor) OpenSSL knows the name-to-OID mapping for serverAuth and clientAuth (among many others), you don't need to do them by hand

Comment: @Maciej Ziniewicz Did you fix this problem. I'm exactly having the same issue and tried the fix below and didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'd just update the DNS section to:

```
[ alt_names ]
DNS.0 = localhost
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
IP.2 = 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the self signed cert to work with just an IP (not a domain name), specify a subject alternative name (SAN) for the IP.

vim req.conf

```
[req]
default_bits = 4096
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
C = US
ST = WA
L = Seattle
O = NoCompany
OU = Orgainizational_Unit
CN = 10.0.0.2
[v3_req]
keyUsage = keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
IP.1 = 10.0.0.2
openssl req -new -nodes -x509 -days 365 -keyout dockerregistry.key -out
```

dockerregistry.crt -config req.conf

On client machine, if you're doing this for a private registry:

```
sudo vim /etc/docker/daemon.json

{
    "insecure-registries" : [ "10.0.0.2:5000" ]
}

sudo systemctl restart docker
```